# When pushing a new value inside an array it gets totally override - VUEX

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs3

Hello so I am creating a filter search and I 'm trying to collect all the key (tags) that the user press, inside an array, however every time that a new value is push it does override the entire array. So I tried a couple of things, like spread syntax, concat, etc. But with no luck.

So my action looks like this:

```
const setCurrentFilters = async (context, payload) => {

    if (payload) {
    
        context.commit('setCurrentFilter');

    }
}
```

My state

```
state:{
filters: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentFilters') || '[]'),
}
```

The mutation

```
        setCurrentFilter(state, payload) {
            state.filters.push(payload);
sessionStorage.setItem('currentFilters', JSON.stringify(payload));
        }
```

And my getter

```
        currentFilters(state) {
            return state.filters;
        },
```

Thank you in advance for any help : )

Comment: Shouldn't if be if(!filter.length) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you set `const filters = [];` which means that the next condition `if (filters.length)` will always return false (as you just created this array) and therefore the else statement will execute.

in the else statement you basically push the new payload to the empty array you just initialized - which makes your array always hold only the new value

i believe that you just need to remove the `const filters = [];` line, and access the `filters` property that exists in your state

Comment: Hi Liad, thank you for your answer, I tried this, by making the push over the mutation instead, because mutations can modify the states directly, so I removed the array as  suggested from my action const setCurrentFilters = async (context, payload) => {if (payload) {
context.commit('setCurrentFilter');}}  and my state will looks like setCurrentFilter(state, payload) {state.filters.push(payload);} but I still have the same result, is being override

Comment: could you please post the new code as an edit in your post?